# Is there a hotkey to exit Intellisense when writing code within a function?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2017

I typically get annoyed when writing code within a `Func` or `Action` of a parameter from a method and the Intellisense of the method is always popping up when I'm in some white space or done editing a line.

A good example is Task.Run:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    string test = default;
    // Sometimes Intellisense of Task.Run pops up anywhere within here
}
```

Obviously I know one way around this is to delegate to a method:

```
Task.Run((Action)DoWork)

public void DoWork()
{
    string test = default;
}
```

Another solution I found is to hit `Alt` key twice because that activates the top menu and the second click disables and focuses back where you last were. Is there a hotkey I am not aware of and could not find that closes Intellisense when I don't need it? I know `Ctrl + Shift + Space` opens it.

Note: I have Resharper and using their Intellisense. I noticed Visual Studio's has the problem but closes if you go left or right with the vertical typing bar.

Comment: Try Esc key. Without Resharper it simple closes Intellisense.

Comment: That does not close it for me.